# Quick debugging question [Python, pygame]

Tags: python, debugging, pygame, livewires

It's still an incomplete program, but for some reason the value of the textbox doesn't increase when it should... Why is this??
When the Pizza sprite overlaps with the Pan sprite, the score in the textbox is supposed to increase in value by 10. Why does this not occur?

Thanks!

```
'''
Created on Jul 1, 2011

@author: ******* Louis
'''
#Watch me do.
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init (screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

#Pizza Class
class Pizza (games.Sprite):
    pizzaimage = games.load_image ("pizza.bmp", transparent = True)
    def __init__(self, x = random.randrange(640), y = 90, dy = 4):
        super (Pizza, self).__init__(x = x, 
                                     y = y,
                                     image = Pizza.pizzaimage, 
                                     dy = dy)

    def handle_caught (self):
        self.destroy()


class Pan (games.Sprite):
    panimage = games.load_image ("pan.bmp", transparent = True)
    def __init__ (self, x = games.mouse.x, y = games.mouse.y):
        super (Pan, self).__init__(x = x, 
                                   y = y, 
                                   image = Pan.panimage)
        self.score = 0
        self.textbox = games.Text (value = str(self.score),
                                    size = 20,
                                    color = color.black,
                                    x = 550,
                                    y = 50)
        games.screen.add(self.textbox)


    def update (self): #WWWWOW There is actually an *update* method
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        self.y = games.mouse.y

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        if self.right >640:
            self.right = 640
        if self.top < 0:
            self.top = 0
        if self.bottom > 480:
            self.bottom = 480 
        self.check_collision()

    def check_collision (self):
        for Pizza in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score = self.score + 10
            Pizza.handle_caught()


#main
def main():
    wallbackground = games.load_image ("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = wallbackground

    games.screen.add(Pizza())

    games.screen.add(Pan())
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True

    games.screen.mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textbox takes a value that is a string. When you create the textbox, you create a string from the current value of score, and set the text to that string. No lasting connection between score and textbox is made.

The textbox probably has a method available to update its text; call that method with the value `str(self.score)` after you increment the score.

Comment: Hmm... I know of another way to do it which would be changing score to the attribute self.textbox.value = _____

But I was more concerned with the logic of the thing. Why wouldn't the score change? The variable is the same that gets incremented, and the mainloop() at the end of all the code endlessly loops the code as is necessary for all games of this sort... So I'd really appreciate it if you could explain the logic.

Comment: The textbox is created in Pan's `__init__` function - i.e., once for each Pan object that's created. That's the only place the textbox value is set. It's important to realize that `str(self.score)` is an immutable string built based on the current numeric value of `self.score` at the time of Pan's creation. That's a very different thing from the variable named by `self.score`. Strings in python are immutable, as well, so even if you created a string member of Pan to hold the string representation of the score, and pointed textbox at it, it still wouldn't auto-update.